# How to change your website from HTTP to HTTPS on AWS S3 CloudFront? (namecheap domain)

Tags: amazon-s3, https, ssl-certificate, amazon-cloudfront, namecheap

I have been trying to follow [this](https://benjamincongdon.me/blog/2017/06/13/How-to-Deploy-a-Secure-Static-Site-to-AWS-with-S3-and-CloudFront/#fn:4) tutorial to change my website from HTTP to HTTPS. 
I have my website set up with a namecheap domain and AWS S3 for hosting. 
According to the tutorial, I successfully got the SSL certificate. But not sure how to use it to make my website HTTPS.
I am having a problem following step 3 of the tutorial

```
"Under “Default Cache Behavior Settings", select “Redirect HTTP to HTTPS” to try to enforce HTTPS on all requests to CloudFront."
```

I cannot find a cache behavior setting in cloudfront. I only see my 1 cloudfront distribution. And I am only able to edit these fields:

SO how/where can I find the settings to change it to HTTPS?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using an RTMP distribution instead of a CloudFront Web Distribution. Make a new Web Distribution then:

1. Select your distribution by clicking the checkbox next to its name
2. Click Disribution Settings
3. Click Behaviors and click the checkbox next to the Default (*) behavior
4. Click "Edit" and change "Viewer Protocol Policy" to "Redirect HTTP to HTTPS"
5. Click "Yes, Edit"

Note: Make sure you have a valid SSL cert configured

[AWS Docs on Cloudfront HTTP/HTTPS behaviors](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/using-https-viewers-to-cloudfront.html)

Comment: Thanks a lot! Such a silly error! I've been stuck for so many hours. Thanks!